# Make my local host be accessible through DNS and not through IP

Tags: networking, dns, localhost

Is it possible to get a "something.com" domain name, and point that to my local host IP so people would be able to access the site I have running on a specific port trough "something.com" instead of going trough http://my_ip:port?

Everything on my local machine is configured, the site is IIS the port is forwarded and the site is accessible from outside my LAN with my IP.

If it would be simpler, I'm looking to connect only one user to myself, whose IP is not know and it is also unknown if their IP is static or not.

(I believe mine is static)

Comment: Setup a DNS entry for your IP. If you're on a normal ISP connection you probably would want to use something like DynDNS. Otherwise you would need to register a domain name and point it to the IP you specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have these options:

1. Easiest for remote user: you can buy the domain something.com and point its DNS record to your ip address.
2. Easiest for you: The remote user can open his hosts file and configure something.com to point to your ip address.
3. You can setup DynDNS - a DNS entry that will automatically update if your IP is not static. Still - it won't be something.com unless you own it.
4. You can setup your own DNS server with authoritative entry for something.com, remote user will have to use your DNS server.